# Как скрыть родительские элементы утерянных картинок в галерее lightbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery

В галерее лайтбокс не хватает превью картинок. Как скрыть совсем элементы списка `li`, где превью не найдена?

```
<ul class="gallery">

<li><a href="http://domain.ru/images/30652.jpg" title="" rel="lightbox-atomium"> 
    <img src="http://domain.ru/images/30652t.jpg">   
</a> </li>
(здесь все нормально)    
    <li><a href="http://domain.ru/images/30653.jpg" title="" rel="lightbox-atomium"> 
    <img src="">
(а тут утеряна картинка превьюшки, ссылки нет)
</a> 
 </li>
</ul>
```

Выбрать смог посредством jQuery:

```
var spiski = $('a:has(img[src=""])');
```

Как теперь скрыть родителей?

Answer (score 0):

Решение выглядит так:

```
$(this).parent().hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

Используйте событие `error`. Так можно найти не только пустые `src`, но и другие недействительные.

```js
$('.gallery img').on('error',function(){
  $(this).parents('li').hide();
})
```

```css
.gallery li{
  display:inline-block;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border:1px solid;
}
.gallery img{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  display:block;
  object-fit:cover;
  object-position:center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="gallery">
  <li>
    <a href="http://cs6.pikabu.ru/post_img/2014/04/25/10/1398441701_23064248.jpg" title="" rel="lightbox-atomium">
      <img src="http://cs6.pikabu.ru/post_img/2014/04/25/10/1398441701_23064248.jpg" />
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="http://domain.ru/images/30653.jpg" title="" rel="lightbox-atomium">
      <img src="" />
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="http://cs6.pikabu.ru/post_img/2014/04/25/10/1398441701_23064248.jpg" title="" rel="lightbox-atomium">
      <img src="http://cs6.pikabu.ru/post_img/2014/04/25/10/1398441701_23064248.jpg" />
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="http://domain.ru/images/30653.jpg" title="" rel="lightbox-atomium">
      <img src="./dfgdfg/dfg.jpg" />
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Не знаю. Ваш код не работает в моём случае, консоль Хрома зависает

Comment: @РадиоГага , странно, у меня в Google Chrome работает. Имеется в виду рабочий сайт или сниппет на SO?

Comment: Рабочий сайт. Но сейчас поразобрался. Ваш скрипт только скрывает не найденые превьюшки

Comment: В общем, не знаю почему но событие on error у меня вообще не срабатывает

Comment: @РадиоГага , судя по вашему следующему вопросу, вы ловите событие `error` на `<a>`, а нужно на `<img>`